# DD-WRT wireless autoconnect command?

Tags: wireless-networking, dd-wrt

What is command in DD-wrt v24-sp2 build (14896) to autoconnect one specific wireless network as client mode?

Answer (score 0):

from my experience with DD-WRT as a client, its usually auto connects to saved network itself.
you have more then one network saved on it ?

it is on gateway or router mode ?

can you please give a bit more info, to work on.

Comment: Got it, nvram set wl_ssid="put name here"
was command